# Why is fragment data fetched but not accessible by Relay mutation

Tags: graphql, relayjs

I have mutation ([code](https://github.com/calebmer/postgraphql/blob/feat/relay-example/examples/forum-relay/src/mutations.js#L54-L86)) in which I want to delete a node. It has a dependency on the post rowId — which is the primary key of the row in the database — and the viewer id. When the pertaining component ([code](https://github.com/calebmer/postgraphql/blob/feat/relay-example/examples/forum-relay/src/components/Post.js#L22-L31)) gets rendered. The following queries are sent

```
query Queries {
  viewer {
    id,
    ...F1
  }
}
fragment F0 on Viewer {
  id
}
fragment F1 on Viewer {
  id,
  ...F0
}
```

and

```
query Queries($id_0:ID!) {
  post(id:$id_0) {
    id,
    ...F2
  }
}
fragment F0 on Post {
  id,
  rowId
}
fragment F1 on Post {
  rowId,
  id
}
fragment F2 on Post {
  headline,
  body,
  id,
  ...F0,
  ...F1
}
```

The response I get includes the `viewer.id` and `post.rowId`. As you can see here,

```
{
  "data": {
    "post": {
      "id": "cG9zdDo0",
      "headline": "You hit me with a cricket bat.",
      "body": "Hello.",
      "rowId": 4
    }
  }
}
```

and here,

```
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "id": "viewer"
    }
  }
}
```

However when I want to pass them to the `DeletePostMutation` like so `this.props.post.id` they are `undefined`. When I inspect `this.props.post`, I get the following

[image: console]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error suggests that the props passed down to DeletePostMutation is not data fetched by Relay, and looking at the [code](https://github.com/calebmer/postgraphql/blob/feat/relay-example/examples/forum-relay/src/components/Post.js#L22-L31) it seems you are constructing a new object for the **post** and the **viewer** as opposed to sending the **post and viewer** fetched by relay.

I see you are doing this:

```
  handleDelete(event) {
    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
      new DeletePostMutation({
        post: { rowId: this.props.post.rowId },
        viewer: { id: this.props.viewer.id },
      })
    )
  }
```

Try this instead:

```
  handleDelete(event) {
    this.props.relay.commitUpdate(
      new DeletePostMutation({
        post: this.props.post,
        viewer: this.props.viewer,
      })
    )
  }
```

Since you are already composing the GraphQL fragments of **DeletePostMutation** inside the **Post Relay Container** then inside DeletePostMutation each prop should have the fields defined in the fragments accessible.

Comment: @jose-r-cruz thanks so much. Banging my head now. Should have thought about that 